# Dihedral subgroup of a infinite Coxeter group

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups, reflection

I have seen a conclusion that every infinite Coxeter group contain an infinite dihedral subgroup, but I have no idea how to prove it. Could anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Your question is badly lacking details. To begin with, where did you see this conclusion? Was the Coxeter group assumed to be finitely generated? (Then the conclusion is true but takes some effort to prove.) If not, consider the infinite direct product of order 2 groups.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan. Very sorry for my terrible description. I heard this conclusion from an online lecture recently without more details about it, and I forgot to check some group with infinite generators. Could you please tell me some main step of the proof in finitely generated cases? Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, this property is false if you allow infinitely generated Coxeter groups, for instance, the direct sum of infinitely many ${\mathbb Z}_2$'s is an infinite Coxeter group without infinite dihedral subgroups.
2. Assuming that $W$ is a finitely generated infinite Coxeter group, always contains two reflections in parallel hyperplanes (with respect to, say, Tits-Bourbaki representation). For simplicity, I will assume that $W$ is irreducible and of "hyperbolic type." Let $W\to GL(V)$ be the Tits-Bourbaki representation of $W$. 
   Let $\Omega\subset V$ be the (open) Tits cone of the action of $W$ on $V$. Each reflection $\tau\in W$ fixes a linear hyperplane $H_\tau$ in $V$. Two reflections $\tau, \sigma$ are said to have parallel walls if
   $$
   H_\tau \cap H_\sigma \cap \Omega=\emptyset. 
   $$
   One verifies that such reflections $\tau,\sigma$ generate an infinite dihedral subgroup. The existence of reflections with parallel walls in each infinite Coxeter group of finite rank (Parallel Wall Property) was first stated and proven in

Davis, M.W., Shapiro, M.D.: Coxeter groups are automatic. Ohio Slate University (1991) (preprint).

Aparently, their proof was incomplete (do not ask me what was missing), the gap was fixed in:

*Brink, Brigitte; Howlett, Robert B.*, [**A finiteness property and an automatic structure for Coxeter groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01445101), Math. Ann. 296, No. 1, 179-190 (1993). [ZBL0793.20036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0793.20036).

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!